# Incorrect response when using RestSharp however it works well for httpclient

Tags: c#, restsharp

Getting a Bad Request on my Json if I use RestSharp, however it works well with httpClient. The response from the API is not recoganised and its a bad request. The first string SerialNumber is NULL in debugger. Can somebody help to fix the encoding.

```
            RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient(BaseUrl);
            RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("/api/mobileservice/commissionv2", RestSharp.Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset = utf - 8");
            var strJSONContent = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"NexoController.SerialNumber", "AJUTESTDEVICE" },
                {"NexoController.FirmwareVersion", "80" }, 
                {"Retailer.Name", "TestShop" },
                {"Retailer.StoreId", "1" },
                {"Retailer.HasCompetitorCoolers", "true" },
                {"Retailer.CompetitorCoolerCount", "D82" },
                {"Cooler.CoolerManufacturerId", "0"},
                {"Cooler.ModelId", "1"},
                {"Cooler.ShelfCount", "5"},
                {"Cooler.Serial", "string"},
                {"Cooler.PositionId", "0"},
                {"Cooler.CustomerAssetId", "AJUTESTCUSTOMERASSETID"},
                {"Cooler.IsLocatedNextToCompetitorCooler", "true"},
                {"Cooler.ChannelId", "0"},
                {"Cooler.CoolerOtherManufacturerName", "string"},
                {"Cooler.CoolerOtherModelName", "string"},
                {"Beacon.Major", "210" },
                {"Beacon.Minor", "240" },
                {"PeriodTimeUTC", "string"},
                {"UtcOffset", "0"},
                {"Meta.BrandId", "1"},
                {"Meta.AccountNameId", "1"},
                {"DevicePosition.SerialNumber", "string"},
                {"DevicePosition.DeviceId", deviceId},
                {"DevicePosition.FirmwareVersion", "string"},
                {"DevicePosition.MDeviceUUID", "1"},
                {"DevicePosition.Position.Lat", "1"},
                {"DevicePosition.Position.Long", "1"},
                {"DevicePosition.Accuracy", "1"},
                {"DevicePosition.RSSI", "1"},
                {"DevicePosition.DetectionTypeId", "string" },
                {"DevicePosition.LocationAgeSeconds","0" },
                {"DevicePosition.PeriodTimeUTC","string" },
                {"DevicePosition.UtcOffset","0" },
                {"DevicePosition.UploadedBy","Aju" }
            };                
            //add parameters and token to request
            request.Parameters.Clear();                
            request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strJSONContent), ParameterType.RequestBody);
            request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
            //make the API request and get a response
            var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a POCO to store the JSON content, you can use the AddJsonBody method,
where body is an object:

```
RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient(BaseUrl);
RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("/api/mobileservice/commissionv2", RestSharp.Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset = utf - 8");

request.AddJsonBody(body); 

request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

And RestSharp should handle the serialization internally.
The names of the properties for the POCO should match the keys of your JSON